# Change default save for macros in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, macros

I have write protected my normal.dotm because I don't want the macros saved there.  It also warns me if a document I have opened has some virus that tries to save itself to normal.dotm.

I would like the default save to change to the current document when I record macros.  I can't find a setting for that.  Almost all the internet searches I've done have an answer for how to save a document using a macro: not how to change the default save for macros.

How do I change the default save for macros in Word to the current document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer is that you do not.**
The Normal.dotm file is the default save location. There is not an optional setting to make it anything else.

That does not mean you have to save your macros there.
I have thousands of macros and seldom save one there.
You can save to the current document or its attached template but have to opt to do that.

Once you record a macro and save it in the normal.dotm file, you can copy and paste it using the vb Editor interface. If your normal.dotm file is not saving, you will need to do this before closing Word.

My usual practice is to save a recorded macro to the current document and then move it to a module in another global template before closing the current document in a .docx format.

Comment: You have said that you can automatically save to the current document.  It is not automatic if you have to change it manually.  The problem is for every macro I create, I have to change the file setting.  This is just so annoying

Comment: My keyboard got ahead of my brain when it typed "automatic." Sorry, I've edited the response.. ------ In the immortal words of our fearless leader (USA) "It is what it is." ---- This has been the way Word has worked as long as it has had recorded macros. You should not need to be recording that many macros, truly. My production macros are virtually all finished in the visual basic editor. ------ Here is the place to ask for a change: https://word.uservoice.com/forums/304924-word-for-windows-desktop-application

Comment: The reason why I record so many macros is to see what the call parameters are or how something is done, like creating a table with 3 cm squares without inner grid lines.  I don't record the macros to keep them.    Then I write the code properly in VBA, VBScript, Office.js or C#.  It is just annoying that whenever I record a macro, I have to change the file setting.  Thanks for the link

Comment: I understand your annoyance. Keep in mind that recorded macros use the Selection object. It is almost always better, when you revise them, to use the Range object instead. It makes code run much more quickly. (I recognize that you probably know this already.)